# Why $\ln x \in L^p ( (0, 1] )$ for $1\leq p < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

Why $\ln x \in L^p ( (0, 1] )$ for $1\leq p < \infty$?

To prove this do I use Holder's inequality as a main method?

I tried to factor $\ln x$ as $x^k \ln x \cdot 1/x^k$ and then tried to

use Holder's but didn't really work out.

Any suggestion or hint?

Comment: If you choose the right $k$, it ought to work, since $x^k\ln x$ is bounded on $(0,1]$ for all $k > 0$. But then using $$\lvert\ln x\rvert \leqslant \frac{C}{x^k}$$ on $(0,1]$ is probably simpler than using Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Very BIG hint: write $x=e^u$ and convert
$$
\int_0^1 |\log x|^p \, dx
$$
into
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 |u|^p e^u \, du.
$$
Now it suffices to remark that $e^u$ decays to zero at $-\infty$ faster than *any* power of $u$.